# XSLT need difference of / and element

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have two scenarios in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/para/item"></xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="para/item"></xsl:template>
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/para/item` is an *absolute* path, it will match all `item` elements that are children of the root element of the document, provided that root element is called `para`, and will match nothing at all if the root element has a different name.

`para/item` is a *relative* path, so it will match all `item` elements that are children of any `para` element anywhere in the document.

Comment: @lan, thanks for this. I understand this **/para/item** exactly.